# Preload images on my Wordpress ajax navigation?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have WordPress with ajax navigation. When you click on the left side link, html in `<div class="page-details"></div>` loads. What I want to do is to preload images that appear in above mentioned div.

Here is my code

```
jQuery.post(ajaxurl, data, function(html) {
    jQuery('.page-details').html('<div class="row">' + html + '</div>');
}).done(function(data) {
    jQuery('.hb-loader').hide();
});
```

What code should I add to preload images before this happens: `jQuery('.hb-loader').hide();`

Answer (score 0):

There is some plugins to preload images. You can search these in github.
Such as:

```
https://github.com/hacke2/preLoad
```

Comment: I have tried some plugins, but it doesnt help because of ajax navigation, whenever I click on a link right side it lazy loads the image and pushes text down after. This black dot is my .hb-loader, I need black dot to disappear after image is preloaded.